# Textarea with Laravel Collective

Tags: laravel, laravelcollective

Hello friends I need make a Textarea with Laravel Collective, regulary I use:

```
<textarea id="txt" name="txt" maxlength="1900" class="form-control" rows=1" onkeypress="return nameFunction(event);">My text</textarea>
```

**How to create a textarea wiht Laravel Collective?**

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How to create a textarea wiht Laravel Collective

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try like this:

```
    Form::textarea('My text', null, [
                    'class'      => 'form-control',
                    'rows'       => 1, 
                    'name'       => 'txt',
                    'id'         => 'txt',
                    'onkeypress' => "return nameFunction(event);"
                ])
```